p-dropdown(primeng) optionDisabled property is not working such unbale to disable the dropdown option
 <p-dropdown [options]="cities"  
        [(ngModel)]="selectedCity"  
        optionLabel="label" 
        optionDisabled="IsActive"></p-dropdown> 


   this.cities = [ 
        { label: 'India', value: 'IND', IsActive: false }, 
        { label: 'Rome', value: 'RM', IsActive: true }, 
        { label: 'London', value: 'LDN', IsActive: false }, 
        { label: 'Istanbul', value: 'IST', IsActive: true }, 
        { label: 'Paris', value: 'PRS', IsActive: false }, 
    ];

I want IsActive false options to be seen grayout but optionDisabled is not setting it.
Is there any property or code I missed ??

please use stackblitz examples on primeng website and replicate the issue


is it what you want please check attached stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/kdhw6giy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdemo%2Fdropdown-disabled-demo.ts
you can use the template for customize dropdown item as per your requirement
  <p-dropdown
    [options]="cities"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedCity"
    optionLabel="label"
    optionDisabled="IsActive"
  >
    <ng-template let-option pTemplate="item">
      <div>
        <div
          [ngStyle]="option.IsActive? {'color': '#ccc', 'cursor': 'default', 'opacity': '0.5'} : ''"
        >
          {{option.label}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </p-dropdown>


Link-only answers are not good answers, neither are code-only answers. Please [edit] your answer and add the relevant parts of the provided link. Furthermore please explain the changes you've made in order to address the issue.

code is the same he told not working so I have attached the code which is working now what's he want after that I can update it

Please have a look at [answer]. If that link disappears over time then your answer isn't worth anything - As already stated code-only answers are not good answers. You are also writing this answer for future, maybe less experienced developers - How are they supposed to know what your thought-process was in order to solve this

updated please check

thank you Chintan for your responses, used ... </ which is working. But is there any possibility or alternative to achieve it without using  selector.

without ng-template disable working for more styling you need to override disable styles <p-dropdown
[options]="cities"
[(ngModel)]="selectedCity"
optionLabel="label"
optionDisabled="IsActive"

